# Official React Tutorial, using Hooks - Component Not Updating

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I started recreating the official React Tutorial using hooks.

I have encountered two issues I am struggling to solve.

Please refer to the CodePen for the full code, including line numbers.

**Full Code**

[CodePen: React Tutorial with Hooks](https://codepen.io/magnusriga/pen/oVogdm?editors=0011)

**Question 1**

```
// Click handler
function handleClick(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // console.log('1) Inside Square click handler');
  props.onUpdate();

  // Logs un-updated value, probably because setState is async
  console.log("props.value", props.value);

  // STACKOVERFLOW QUESTION (Line 18)
  // This still logs un-updated value (null). Why?
  // PS: Line 23 logs the right value
  window.setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("props.value after timeout", props.value);
  }, 1000);
}

// Logs correct value (Line 23)
console.log("props.value outside", props.value);
```

Line 18 logs a passed `prop` from within a handler, in a `setTimeout`. I am aware that `state` is set *asynchronously*, in line 9 (callback from parent). I understand that line 12 logs the value prior to the async `state` update, but I do not understand why the timeout still prints the wrong value.

**Question 2**

```
<div className = "status" >
  {
    (() => {
      console.log("rendering, status:", status);
      return status;
    })()
  }
</div>
```

Why is `status` in line 75 and 76 not reflecting the latest `state` change? I set it in line 62, then directly afterwards update `state`, which in return should cause a re-render with the right value. I am guessing the answer is that re-renders runs the entire function component again, resetting `status` (i.e. *only* `state` is saved). If that is right, how do we know exactly which components re-render on each `state` / `prop` / `context` update?

Comment: I have a guess as to where my confusion lies. When a component re-renders, handlers do NOT run. Only the function body, including return statement runs. So, the order is: 1) User clicks square; 2) Handler runs, causing state to change; 3) State change leads to re-render, which causes function (component) body to re-run (but NOT the handler within it). Is that right?

Comment: On second thought, that does not explain why the timeout does not capture the right props value. The closure kept by the timeout has access to its lexical environment. But, perhaps when the re-render happens the original lexical environment is gone, thus the props value is lost. I am not sure. This touches on core components in JS. Any experts around?

Comment: you really not be careful with closures. This is very dangerous within the whole react hooks environment. This article might help you: https://overreacted.io/how-are-function-components-different-from-classes/

when you created the timeout, the callback will the take the props at the moment the timeout was created, as far as I understood your first problem

Comment: @LorenzWeiß Interesting, thank you. I think my confusion stems from *when* (at what point in time) the `props.value` inside `setTimeout` is assigned. So, `props` inside the timeout closure is not a reference to an object that could change later in time? It always points to the value of `props` whenever the timeout was created?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am no expert so could be wrong a bit.

### Question 1

> why the timeout still prints the wrong value.

Function Components (FC) are different from Class Components (CC) in a way that, 
1. In FC, `props` contains the snapshot value after the render (using JavaScript closure)
1. In CC, `props` contains the updated value even after the render (because `this.props` can be changed as `this` is not immutable).

I've just read [How Are Function Components Different from Classes?](https://overreacted.io/how-are-function-components-different-from-classes/), yesterday and that's how the "wrong" values, `null` are showing up.

Initially, `score` array is `[null x 9]` thus `props.value` is set to `null`.

```js
function Board() {
  const [isXNext, setIsXNext] = React.useState(true);

  // Initialize array with null values
  const initialArray = Array(9).fill(null);
  const [score, setScore] = React.useState(initialArray);

  // onUpdate handler includes index, thus have to be arrow function
  function renderSquare(i) {
    return <Square value={score[i]} onUpdate={() => handleUpdate(i)} />;
  }

...
}
```

And that `null` is closed over to `window.setTimeout` so `props.value` still has `null` after the time out.

```js
  function handleClick(e) {
    ...
    window.setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("props.value after timeout", props.value);
    }, 1000);
  }
```

### Question 2

> Why is status in line 75 and 76 not reflecting the latest state change?

`status` is a local variable not a React state.

```js
let status = `Next player: ${getPlayer()}`;
```

Mutating the `status` like the following won't re-render as React doesn't track the variable.

```js
status = "Winner: " + winner;
```

Maybe you can declare the `status` as a state, like

```js
const [status, setStatus] = React.useState(`Next player: ${getPlayer()}`);
```

And update the status using `setStatus`

```js
if (winner) {
  setStatus("Winner: " + winner);
  console.log("game-won status:", status);
}
```

As mentioned, I've only read [Dan's article](https://overreacted.io/how-are-function-components-different-from-classes/) yesterday so could not be 100% accurate.

Comment: Thank you. So what we are saying is the *first* `props.value`, captured in the timeout closure when the click event happened, is a completely different object than the new `props.value` sent in during the re-render? Since `props` are immutable, the two `props.value`s cannot point to the same object?

Comment: Yes, you are right. To get into deeper, there is a follow-up post https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/#each-render-has-its-own-props-and-state (⚠ Very long!) which explains that each render has its own props & states.

Comment: Thank you, great. As I suspected, on each render React will re-run the function component, and variables in the function body will be overwritten. To keep their values, simply set them to state values (since state is saved between renders). Thus, at each render, the variables are overwritten with values from state and kept intact over time.